# Typical research on experience for physics graduate school applicants

Tags: graduate-admissions, physics

I am applying to US PhD programs in physics. I do not have much research experience because I am an international student transferring from a completely different field. When checking the profiles of people applying to physics PhD programs, a random profile looks like this: 4 REUs in astrophysics and computational fluid Dynamics resulting in 2 first author publications, 10 graduate courses in such and such. If this is a typical profile, then I feel I have no chance getting an admission to a single graduate school.

My question is: To what extent is this representative of physics PhD applications in the United States?

Comment: Try looking at profiles on physicsgre.com or gradCafe. I don't feel that the profile you described is representative of the average applicant. Also I think there is a difference between 'representative of an applicant admitted to a top-5 program' and 'representative of an average physics PhD applicant'.